# Is buying/selling signals (trade suggestions) halal?

Tags: halal-haram, money, trading

Well the [signals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forex_signal) are predictions made by professionals or not normal people in the trading field (people rating them will determinate that).

So when someone is well rated he can sell his signals for money (he will get buyers for because of his reputation), like saying "USD/BTC will go up 1.235545 at 4 AM".

It's more like a binary system where they predict "up or down" "0 or 1".

I'm not sure about this since I don't see something bad: someone "connected" to the domain selling his skills.

Still need to know if it's allowed in Islam or not.

Comment: How is this not gambling?

Comment: @G.Bach i don't see what gambling stands for in this case? i mean i see it like : i have money, i hire a trading pro, he helps me to choose where to invest :?!

Comment: Can you explain the trade more precisely? It sounds like a bet that the person selling the signals is right. Who gets what in this trade?

Comment: The signal seller will get paid before knowing if it's right or not. For example i have $5000, i don't know where to invest them.. I buy a signal for $50 that tells me where to invest (tbh.. It's like a hint but in %100 of cases i follow that hint lol, who would pay $50 for nothing)

Comment: So what you're buying is the information what he thinks will happen, and nothing else? Is there any possible exchange of money/services/goods bound to that than "I give you X$, tell me what you think will happen"?

Comment: No, there's no trading of money/goods, isn't this a service through? Also it's not i give u x$ , its the seller who makes the offer, and the buyer will not see the signal (only seller's profile and reputation..) Before paying..  Also the system takes 2% fee of the transaction seller/buyer ( i don't think there's a problem here since its the service fee)